# ms sql - import data into a table from multiple tables with different data structure and different ID

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `dbo.action` including all columns as the code below. I want to import data from `dbo.rule`(created, originalAmount, id) into `dbo.action` (timestamp, actualAmount, rule_id) and from `dbo.lendbook` (id) into `dbo.action` (lendbook_id). The rest of columns in `dbo.action` is fixed or nullable values. Below is my code, but the sql server just keep executing without showing any errors or results.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.action
    (timestamp, result, description, request_endpoint, request_payload, 
     response_status, response_payload,
    actualAmount, rule_id, lendbook_id)
SELECT
    t1.created, 'SUCCESS', NULL, '/lendbook/usd', NULL,
    NULL, NULL,
    t1.originalAmount, t1.id, t2.id
FROM [dbo].[rule] t1, dbo.lendbook t2
```

`rule_id` and `lendbook_id` are foreign keys and not null. 3 tables have different unique primary keys

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: make join on `[dbo].[rule]` and `dbo.lendbook` using their relationship

Comment: "just keep executing without showing any errors or results.". Well there's nothing in that statement which would cause any output. Normally a SQL GUI will show the number of rows affected though - does it say that, at least? Or, you can run a separate Select statement to look at the table. And as Gordon said, using commas in your From clause is not a good idea.

Comment: But why are you doing this? If you've got foreign key columns to the rule and lendbook tables, then that's all you need to import, you don't need to copy any other data - that just creates redundant, de-normalised data. Unless you want to create an audit trail, and you're worried that the original records will be modified?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I changed to this: FROM [dbo].[rule] t1
JOIN dbo.lendbook t2 ON t2.id = t1.id  => (0 rows affected) lol

Comment: @ADyson, just loading spinner and "executing query..." and no statement like rows affected, etc.

Comment: I guess it just takes too long then, probably because of the massive join. So you need to try and find the correct join to use. The one you suggested is unlikely to work, unless by some chance both your tables use the same IDs for matching records. Is there any relationship existing between lendbook and rule?

Comment: I don't know how `JOIN` works in this case because tables' IDs are totally different and also other columns only match partially but not all, may be that's why the `JOIN` syntax made 0 rows affected. Here is the change: FROM [dbo].[rule] t1 JOIN dbo.lendbook t2 ON t2.id = t1.id

Comment: yep that'll be why it didn't work. Like I said, is there any relationship existing between lendbook and rule? What is your logic for matching up the rows from lendbook and rule, such that you think they are valid to be in the same row in the "action" table? What requirement are you trying to apply?

Comment: I matched the `rate` column between those two for now, even though this is not really perfect match, but just a temporary solution. Thank you so much for your comments